# Reveal Jquery Modal Close

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, zurb-foundation, zurb-reveal

I have a reveal modal with a form inside the modal, when the users submits the form I would like the modal to close.

Can someone help me with the code for this?

http://zurb.com/playground/reveal-modal-plugin

I've tried changing the "dismissmodalclass" to the class of the submit button

```
$('#modal').reveal({
     animation: 'fadeAndPop',                   //fade, fadeAndPop, none
     animationspeed: 300,                       //how fast animtions are
     closeonbackgroundclick: true,              //if you click background will modal close?
     dismissmodalclass: 'close-reveal-modal'    //the class of a button or element that will close an open modal
});
```

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: What modal are you using? The default jQuery ui one?

Comment: $('#myProvince').submit('reveal', 'close');   "myProvince is the form id"

Comment: I'm using this modal http://zurb.com/playground/reveal-modal-plugin

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking it since this is tagged Foundation that you are using foundation's reveal

In Which case I would recommend that you actually read the documentation for if you did you would know that models can be fired (open or close) via javascript

** An example of firing a modal with java - Cookie Warning**

Before Your Closing body tag with the include for foundation.js :

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var COOKIE_NAME = 'welcome_cookie';
    $go = $.cookie(COOKIE_NAME);
    if ($go == null) {
        $.cookie(COOKIE_NAME, 'This Cookie is used to remember that you have seen our cookie policy', {path: '/', expires: 6});
        $('#myModal').foundation('reveal', 'open');
    }
    else {
    }
});
</script>
```

the modal:

```
<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal small" data-reveal>
<h2>This Site Uses Cookies.</h2>
<p class="lead">Cookie Policy.</p>
<p>To give you the best experience, this site uses cookies, By continuing to use this website you are giving consent to cookies being used. For information on cookies and how you can disable them visit <a href="">here</a></p>
<a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
```

This is an example for a modal that pops off if the welcome cookie is not present however im sure that all you would need is

```
 $('#myFormModel').foundation('reveal', 'close');
```

Also check the EVENT BINDINGS from the docs

[Zurb Foundations | Docs | Reveal](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/reveal.html)